# A manifold of class $C^k$ always has a countable atlas with structure of class $C^k$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm trying to prove the statement above, and I've got stuck.

Consider $M$ a manifold. By the second axiom of numerability, I can consider the set of all charts $(U_n,\varphi_n)$ in a manifold, and by the second axiom of countability, we know that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n = M$.

I only need to see that the functions associated to the charts verify that $\varphi_n\circ\varphi_m^{-1}$ is a function of class $C^k$ for $U_n\cap U_m\ne\emptyset$, which would be easy to say if all of the $\varphi_n$ were of class $C^k$, but could we say this right away?

Comment: By definition of a $C^k$ manifold, all transition functions $\psi_{\alpha\beta}=\varphi_{\alpha}\circ \varphi_{\beta}^{-1}$ are of class $C^k$.

Comment: Oh, so it is clear though these transition functions. Got it! Thank you so much!